# How to get apps detect phonon_backend

Tags: kde, pdf, okular, phonon

I installed `Okular 1.10` via `snap` and, unlike the previous versions, it can't play videos embedded into pdfs due to the backend problem:

```
WARNING: bool Phonon::FactoryPrivate::createBackend() phonon backend plugin could not be loaded
WARNING: Phonon::createPath: Cannot connect Phonon::MediaObject ( no objectName ) to  Phonon::AudioOutput ( no
objectName ).
```

No matter how hard I try to `export QT_PLUGIN_PATH` with all the libs installed by

```
sudo apt install phonon4qt5 phonon4qt5-backend-gstreamer phonon4qt5-backend-vlc
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install phonon-backend-vlc
```

it still yields the same error.

`strace` doesn't even help to find out where `Okular` is trying to search the backend for.

Any hints?

I install `Okular` via snap because the Ubunutu's repository has an old version with a [bug](https://www.mail-archive.com/kde-bugs-dist@kde.org/msg272018.html) which nobody takes care of, namely, crash after quitting presentation mode.

Comment: Why do you not want to install Okular from *deb*?

Comment: @N0rbert Because the version via `apt` is buggy -- it crashes after quitting presentation mode.